# Updating grid size for converting 2D lines to color-mesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I have multiple 2D lines, and I tried to convert into color-mesh based on number of lines crossing in each grid. Grid size is fixed to be 0.001.
My script does not give any error, but the line width is much more than assigned grid (0.001). Here I am showing a demo data and my script.

Meanwhile, I am changing the grid size, but it seems not to be effective:

**I have tried multiple times, and now at the end of the day I am sharing my question here for any suggestion.**

```
# data format: 
['104.53299713134766 29.43440055847168 104.46289 29.44242\n',
 '104.53299713134766 29.43440055847168 104.46199 29.44128\n']


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

grid_size = 0.001  # Set the grid size

density_map = {}

x_min, x_max = 104.4, 104.60
y_min, y_max = 29.35, 29.55

# Set the precision for grid cell calculation
getcontext().prec = 10

# Read lines from the file
with open(LF_path, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Iterate over the lines
for line in lines[0:1]:
    line = line.strip().split()
    # Convert the line coordinates to floats with higher precision
    line = [Decimal(coord) for coord in line]

    # Calculate the grid cell coordinates for the start and end points of the line
    start_x = int(line[0] / Decimal(grid_size))
    start_y = int(line[1] / Decimal(grid_size))
    end_x = int(line[2] / Decimal(grid_size))
    end_y = int(line[3] / Decimal(grid_size))

    # Update the density map for each point in the line
    for x in range(min(start_x, end_x), max(start_x, end_x) + 1):
        for y in range(min(start_y, end_y), max(start_y, end_y) + 1):
            # Check if the point is within the specified range
            if x_min <= (x * Decimal(grid_size)) <= x_max and y_min <= (y * Decimal(grid_size)) <= y_max:
                if (x, y) in density_map:
                    density_map[(x, y)] += 1
                else:
                    density_map[(x, y)] = 1


# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the density map
x_coords, y_coords, values = zip(*[(x[0] * Decimal(grid_size), x[1] * Decimal(grid_size), y) for x, y in density_map.items()])
scatter = ax.scatter(x_coords, y_coords, c=values, s=0.1, cmap='rainbow')


# Add colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter, label='Density')

# Set the map range
ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)

ax.grid(True, which='both', linewidth=0.5, linestyle='-', color='gray')
```

Here is the output which has clear width more than 0.001 gridsize.,

[image]